# Stop Synergy using 25% CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, synergy

I just upgraded to Synergy 1.7.3 and now my Windows PC is stuck at 25% CPU usage permanently!  It's caused by `synergyd.exe`.  I can end-task on it without any problems (doesn't stop Synergy from working), but when I reboot it comes back and sits at 25% CPU usage.  The machine is quad core so I suspect it is stuck at 100% CPU in a single thread.

I tried deleting `synergyd.exe` but when I reboot I get an MSI installer window popping up briefly and then the file is back again, so I can't seem to prevent it from running.  Does anyone know what this is and how to stop it from constantly sucking 25% CPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this bug has since been fixed.  Upgrading to the latest [nightly release](https://synergy-project.org/nightly) (synergy-master-bd3a8e9) fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I think one work around which worked for me was to keep the Synergy UI open on the desktop. You should be able to minimize it but leave it open.